# Assign locators to time not bars

Tags: ableton-live

I'm creating a track which has widely variable tempos. I would like to add locators in arrangement view but it seems that the locators are tied to the bars and not to the time of the track. I would like to achieve the following

00:00 - 04:00 Intro

04:00 - 10:00 Section 1

10:00 - 15:00 Section 2

15:00 - 30:00 Section 3

Section 1, 2 and 3 have varied tempos and I am not sure what these are going to be from the start. I just want to start with the layout and then when I decide what my tempos are going to be not have to move the locators. Is this possible? By the way, I'll probably have around 20-30 sections for a track that will be around an hour. This is probably a common case.

Comment: You might be able to get _some_ help if you add a 30 minute audio clip at the beginning of the piece, and turn off warping, so the clip's contents stay minute/second based. It's not locators, but it can at least work as a visual map of sorts. Though is that any better than the minute:second time ruler.